# как сделать update mysql массивом php используя именные параметры

Tags: php, mysql

Ключи и значения двух переданных в функцию массивов собираю в отдельные переменные, чтобы подставить их в именные параметры.

Но выдаёт ошибку:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given ... on line 29

29 строка вот:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($post, 'ssssssssss', $key[0], $value[0], $key[1], $value[1], $key[2], $value[2], $key2[0], $value2[0], $key2[1], $value2[1]);
```

я так понимаю в $post ничего не попадает, почему?

$table - название таблицы

$data - массив, который обновит данные в таблице

$conditions - массив, ключи(столбцы таблицы) и значения(поля таблицы) которого будут условием замены данных

$comparator - передаю напрямую 'AND' для нескольких условий

```
public function update($table, $data, $conditions, $comparator) {
        $key = array_keys($data);
        $value = array_values($data);
        $key2 = array_keys($conditions);
        $value2 = array_values($conditions);
        $post = mysqli_prepare($this->mysqli, "UPDATE $table SET ? = ?, ? = ?, ? = ? WHERE ? = ? $comparator ? = ?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($post, 'ssssssssss', $key[0], $value[0], $key[1], $value[1], $key[2], $value[2], $key2[0], $value2[0], $key2[1], $value2[1]);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($post);
    }
```

Comment: Ну ихним же по белому пишут, что `$post` - boolean, хотя должен быть mysqli_stmt. Не иначе mysqli_prepare сбоит... что может быть следствием некорректного $this->mysqli... что, в свою очередь ... в общем, проверяйтесь на ошибки.

Comment: @Akina чего там проверять? весь запрос ошибка одна. имена таблиц и полей пытаются параметризовать.

Comment: а не, таблица подставляется. но имена полей все равно представлены как параметры, чего быть не может.

Comment: @teran *чего там проверять?* а в запросе 10 параметров, хотя привязывается 11...

Comment: И да - подстановку имён полей надо выполнять напрямую. а не параметрически.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $post = mysqli_prepare($this->mysqli, "UPDATE $table SET $key[0] = ?, $key[1] = ?, $key[2] = ? WHERE $key2[0] = ? $comparator $key2[1] = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($post, $value[0], $value[1], $value[2], $value2[0], $value2[1]);
```

Comment: благодарю, я почему-то думал, что ключи можно передать как и значения